# Open AI file at zoom setting "fit to screen"

Tags: adobe-illustrator, zoom

I work on A4 sized artboards most of the time. However, when I open a file (saved as PDF), AI always opens it zoomed out (about 60%) which is too small for me to see the details. Having to press cmd+0 every single time a file opens is starting to get on my nerves, and I've tried searching for a "open at zoom level x as default" setting, but haven't been able to find anything.

Is there a way to do this in Illustrator?